# Adding html to previously defined buttons

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I created a website with an online software (for a nice design). While I created it, I added buttons that didnt point anywhere.

I am at the point where, I would connect these buttons to my own html to produce D3 visualizations. However, the buttons are not currently easy to find in the html code from the site.

Is there a way I can still retrieve these already rendered buttons to connect them to my D3 code?
Or maybe there is a way to pinpoint the location of them? I have no idea otherwise.

Comment: What did you already try ?

Comment: I have been searching through w3schools.com for a solution to this.

Comment: Do you want to hardcode the functionality to the buttons or programmatically code the functionality?

Comment: I need to programmatically code the functionally using D3. For each button clicked, there will be a display of statistical information on the same webpage.

Comment: try d3.select("button") or d3.select(".btn")? see if it gets anything.

Comment: there are multiple buttons, so how would i differentiate between them if i dont have immediate access to the name? they display on the webpage though.